# C++ memory table

Tags: c++

Can anyone recommend a **lightweight** open source C++ table data structure that has data access similar to a database table? (i.e. a 2D array but with named columns - ideally, each column will hold data of a single type [see below]).

I have had a quick look on Google, but have not found anything very useful.

The way I see it, these are the options available to me:

1. Write my own from scratch (don't really want to invent the wheel)
2. rip out the SimpleResult class from mySQL++ and hack around it
3. use [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/index.html) (don't know how lightwight this will be - since I don't need the querying engine and all the other stuff)
4. Ask in here to see if anyone is aware of such a library

So here I am, choosing the quickest route (hopefully one that will also prove to be the the most efficient use of my time - since whatever is recommended here is likely to be peer reviewed).

So, can anyone recommend a C++ class/ set of classes that provides a "database table like" interface?

The main requirements are:

1. Columns have names
2. Cells can be accessed using row, column indexes
3. I Can add rows and columns to the  table (ideally, I can remove them too)
4. (Nice to have): columns can have types, so it saves teh cost of converting to/from strings

**[EDIT]**

To further demonstrate how I want to use the library, please see the pseudo code below to see simple use of such a class (simple, meaning now iteration of rows and columns - which would be really cool). For now just keeping things simple:

```
typedef MemoryTable::ColType ColumnType;

table = new MemoryTable();

// Set up the structure (this can be modified later using removeColumn() etc
table->addColumn(ColumnType::Integer, 'id');
table->addColumn(ColumnType::String,  'name');
table->addColumn(ColumnType::Boolean, 'gender');
table->addColumn(ColumnType::Double,  'weight');

for (size_t i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    table->addRow();
    numrows = table->getNumRows();
    std::cout << "We now have " << numrows << " rows.\n";

    // Note can access cells using column name or index 
    // Also using generic value getter/setter methods. Can throw exception on type mismatch
    table->setValue(i, 'id', i*i);
    table->setValue(i, 'name', getRandomSimpsonCharacterName());

    //just to show use of a getter method
    table->setValue(i, 'gender', checkGender(table->getValue(i, 'name')));
    table->setValue(i, 3, guessWeight(table->getValue(i, 'name')));
}
```

Comment: Ooh there are lots of these around. You can get my own version as part of the alib library for my FOSS tool CSVfix at http://code.google.com/p/csvfix - it's in a_table.cpp. Not great OO code, but it has been used quite a bit.

Comment: Hi Neil, I had a look at your library. although very comprehensive, I dont know if it is capable of the kind of lightweight in memory type operations I want to carry out (please see my edited question). If your library can be used in that manner, then please kindly shed some light (i.e. a few lines of code) on how I may be use you library in the manner described in my question.

Comment: Ok, I wrote up a simple class for this. Currently, it can only hold data for a single data type. Shall I modify this question and post it here for comments/critiscisms/suggestions/enhancements etc? (its approx 250 lines ....

Comment: 250 lines is probably too much for SO. Post a link.

Comment: Ok, I posted the code here: http://pastebin.com/m518306b5  I'll be grateful for some feedback/collaborative editing to make the class better (I wrote it in a hurry, so it is likely to have some bugs). Someone who is familiar with BOOST::any can probably modify the code so that instead of being a class template, it can be a regular class that stores Boost::any values instead. Also the mem alloc scheme could be improved - its currently using the default, so its not very effecient (and will probably leaked if thrashed in a mega loop that adds loads of rows .... feedback will be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

For creating from scratch (very big scratch) try [Boost Multi-index Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). It is not really a database implementation but it could help.

Comment: Can columns be dynamically added to a multi_index?

Comment: It is not possible to add indices at runtime, but your structure could contain dynamic list of columns.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with sqlite or Berkeley DB. They're fast, are designed to run well with "in memory" tables. Google for "embedded database" for other options.

Answer (score 2):

Can `std::vector<std::vector<std::string/boost::any?> >` be considered a candidate?

Comment: Possibly, yes. I have used it sparingly in the past, so I'll have to take a second look. I am going to have a stab at writing a simple class first

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a_table.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace ALib;

int main()
{
    Table table;
    table.AddColumn( Column( "id", Column::Integer ));
    cout << "We now have " <<table.Depth() << " rows.\n";
    TableRow row;
    row.push_back( TableValue( 42 ) );
    table.AddRow( row );
    cout << "We now have " <<table.Depth() << " rows.\n";
    string s = table.Value( 0, 0 ).AsString();
    cout << "row[0][0] is " << s << "\n";
    cout << "id[0] value is "
          << table.Value( table.ColumnIndex("id"),0).AsInteger();
}
```

Comment: But Neil, this is the closest thing to an answer I have got so far :). I will vote it up (and it may well be the answer I choose in the end). It comes nearest to what it is I want to do. I'll download your code a bit to familiarize myself with it.

Comment: @Draemon Of course I could. Brain not working, too well - I tend to think (wrongly) CW is only for questions.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a `std::map`.  Simply create an object type that represents a row:

```
struct person {
   int id;
   std::string name;
   bool gender;
   double weight;
};

std::map<std::string, person> table;

// ... insert data, etc.

std::cout << "Homer is " << table["Homer"].weight << " lbs.\n";
person p = table["Marge"];
```

Comment: This fails the "I Can add … columns to the table" requirement since the struct layout cannot be modified at runtime.

Comment: Thank you KennyTM - I'm glad someone is paying attention :)   (Just joking ofcourse!). But yes Max, it is to simple for what I need to do. Thanks all the same however, for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something smarter than `std::map` (my other answer), you may consider [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html), [NetCDF](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/), [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/), [trivial database](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdb/) or similar libraries.  Unfortunately they often generate files, which seems to violate the title of the question.

You may also be interested in embedded systems, such as [embedded MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/products/embedded/), [embedded Firebird](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/Firebird-Embedded-Linux-HOWTO.html), or [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx).

Comment: Actually, I am using BDB as the data source, but I need a nice simple data type that I can use to pass the data around in my application. Ideally, that data type will also provide a simple intrterface of accesing rows/columns etc. To clarify, its not db functionality that I want, but rather the ability to get/Set (and find) values in named columns